# Implementing button click from a custom list view

Tags: java, android

I am using one class which extends ListActivity and One class extending BaseAdapter.
The Base Adapter uses getView function to inflate layout from xml.
The xml contains a text and a button to delete the row of list.
Please let me know how to handle the button click in the ListActivity class.
Send me a sample snapshot
Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with C++? Isn't this Java on Android?

Comment: I edited the tags in case I'm right. Feel free to clarify your question and correct them if I'm not.

Comment: Selected by mistake.Thanks for checking

Comment: public class AndroidList extends ListActivity {
@Override   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
ListImplementation LI = new ListImplementation();
LI.setListItems(someDummyArrayList);
 setListAdapter(LI);
   }


public class ListImplementation extends BaseAdapter 
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{ 
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button) 
b.setOnClickListener(l) 
} 

Now how can i send this button click to my AndroidList class which has the functionality to delete the entire row

Answer (score 0):

just create an on click listener for the item that you want to in your get view.

For instance

```
public class FooAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<T>
////stuff

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
list.get(position)
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button)
b.setOnClickListener(l)//l is a View.OnClickListener type
}
```

that will render a listener for each button in the view